# Squash multiple Pull Requests from one Git project and merge them into another as one PR

Tags: git, github

I have recently cloned a git project and made into a new Repo. I am trying to squash few PRs from the first project into a single PR and pull in the new repo as a single PR. Will this be possible?

(Each PR in project one may have more than one commits within it).

Basically it's a single feature but in different PRs merged at different times. Like feature basics, some bug fixes to it, feedback and spec changes etc etc. Combined however they are all technically one single feature.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't (easily) do this unless the 2 project histories be related.

Comment: The cloned project does have all the history of the first one.

Comment: I tried cherry-picking but it gets quite complex since it takes me through each commit and asks to resolve conflicts and then continue. I just want to resolve conflicts of all the squashed PRs once.

Comment: This is tricky, because the commits you want to squash are all merge commits.  Redoing all the merge commit might be the only way here.

Comment: You could soft reset the branch to the common anchestor with the repository you want to merge it to. Then, create a PR and merge it.

Comment: Besides, isn't it just possible to create a PR to the main project and squash merge that?

Comment: We have a branch in the main project where we do experimental features. Once a feature is approved after several iterations, we need to pull it out into another branch. However other merged features in that experimental branch are not needed. The experimental branch is pointed to a URL so QA and project owners can test it. Recently a feature has been approved and i am trying to only pull code related to it and not other experimental features and create a new branch and then resolve its conflict with the branch i actually need it in.